# Going through an int[,] array of 0's and 1's

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, int, 2d-games

**Text in cursive: Older entries**

**Normal Text: Most updated entry**

*Ok, so I have a 2D array of ints, more specifically, of 0's and 1's.
Originally this was a BMP file (black & white), and I transformed it to an array of ints.
Now, the matrix represents a map, where the 0's are the spots where I can stand( floor if you will), and the 1's are the abyss, or a wall (you can't stand in a 1).
So i need to go through this random array of ints, but i need to be able to go through ALL the 0's of the map. 
It doesn't matter if i visit a "pixel" more than once
What's the point of this? I have a method that "hides" 4 keys in the map, my character has to find them in the map.
My character can only move up, down, left and right. Diagonal movement isn't allowed, and obviously, teleporting isn't allowed either.
So far I have this code:*

```
public void goThrough(int[,] map, int[] pos)
{
    int i = pos[0], j = pos[1]  ;
    while( i < map.GetLength(0) && j < map.GetLength(1) )
    {
        int cont = 0;
        if (map[i, j] == 0) 
        { 
            if (map[i, j + 1] == 0 && cont == 0 ) { j++; cont++; }
            if (map[i + 1, j] == 0 && cont == 0) { i++; cont++; }
            if (map[i, j - 1] == 0 && cont == 0 ) { j--; cont++; }
            if (map[i - 1, j] == 0 && cont == 0 ) { i--; cont++; }
        }
        if (map[i, j] == 1)
        {
        }
    }
}

public int[] Position(int[,] map)
{
    int[] pos = { 0, 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0) && map[pos[0], pos[1]] == 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1) && map[pos[0], pos[1]] == 1; j++)
        {
            pos[0] = i;
            pos[1] = j;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

*It obviously has some mistakes. Please, just send some feedback! Maybe someone with some experience with this kind of code can help me a little :D.*

*Edit1: I'm so sorry I didn't specified the language. This is C#.
To make a quick update too:
I tried creating another int[,] (exactly the same as the first), and every time my "explorer" goes through any (x,y), I add one(1) to this position of the (second, the copied one) array. This way I can make a method that recognizes when I fully "explore" the map.
Also, with this "copied" array, I can choose another direction if I'm in a position that the explorer was before (that spot will NOT be a 0 in the second array, actually, every time the explorer passes through that spot, it will add one (1) to that position in the array). The idea is to make the explorer behave differently when he has passed through the same spot once, or twice, or more...but ALL this isn't working at all. I'm getting endless loops still...*

EDIT2: Now I have this code:

```
    public void goThrough(int[,] map, int[] pos, bool[,] visited)
    {
        int x = pos[0];
        int y = pos[1];
        visited[x, y] = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Position -> Column: {0} || Row: {1}", x, y);
        // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
        if (y > 0 && map[x, y - 1] == 0 && !visited[x, y - 1])
        {
            goThrough(map, new[] { x, y + 1 },visited); // north
            // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
        }
        if (x < map.GetLength(0) - 1 && map[x + 1, y] == 0 && !visited[x + 1, y])
        {
            goThrough(map, new[] { x + 1, y }, visited); // east
            // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
        }
        if (y < map.GetLength(1) - 1 && map[x, y + 1] == 0 && !visited[x, y + 1])
        {
            goThrough(map, new[] { x, y - 1 }, visited); // south
            // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
        }
        if (x > 0 && map[x - 1, y] == 0 && !visited[x - 1, y])
        {
            goThrough(map, new[] { x - 1, y }, visited); // west
            // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
        }
        if (NoZeros(visited)) { Console.WriteLine("I went through everything!"); Console.ReadLine(); }


    }
```

Notice the WriteLine i put, so I can have track of every iteration of this recursive method.
This is the output:

```
Position -> Column: 1 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 2 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 3 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 4 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 5 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 6 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 7 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 8 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 9 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 10 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 10 || Row: 32
Position -> Column: 11 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 12 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 13 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 13 || Row: 32
Position -> Column: 14 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 15 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 16 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 16 || Row: 32
Position -> Column: 17 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 18 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 19 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 20 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 21 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 22 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 23 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 24 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 25 || Row: 31
Position -> Column: 25 || Row: 30
Position -> Column: 1 || Row: 30
```

So, first of all, this method DIDN'T go through all the maze, not even close ( and yes, the 0's are all connected).

Second, in the last iteration (Last 2 lines of the output), the explorer "teleported" from (25,30) to (1,30).

By the way, this is the image:

[image: White =0's & Black =1's]

Answer (score 3):

At first it sounds like you're just looking for a [maze solving algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm); something like the left-hand wall follower.

However, you're not looking for a path out of a maze, you're looking to visit all the contiguous locations with the same value. So essentially you can use a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill_algorithm).

The only gotcha is that you might have multiple pools of `0`s that are not connected (unless your original bitmap was constructed so that all the 0s would be connected, in which case you can make sure all the keys are reachable by only ever putting them on 0 cells). So you might need to do the flood fill from multiple starting points to make sure everything is covered.

Comment: The 0's are ALL conected. Always. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a tree with all the possible paths that you encounter. Each node represents a certain point in your map and all children represent valid points that you can go to. Each point that has been visited is marked so that you don't try to visit it again. If you then perform a depth-first tree search you could walk around until you have explored all possible locations. Whenever you encounter a visited node you don't go there again. The following performs a recursive depth-first search. For large maps you will need a non-recursive solution or you'll get a StackOverflowException.

```
private bool[,] visited; // needs to have same size as map
public void GoThrough(int[,] map, int[] pos) {
  int x = pos[0];
  int y = pos[1];
  visited[x, y] = true;
  // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
  if (y > 0 && map[x, y - 1] == 0 && !visited[x, y - 1]) {
    GoThrough(map, new [] {x, y - 1}); // north
    // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
  }
  if (x < map.GetLength(0) - 1 && map[x + 1, y] == 0 && !visited[x + 1, y]) {
    GoThrough(map, new [] {x + 1, y}); // east
    // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
  }
  if (y < map.GetLength(1) - 1 && map[x, y + 1] == 0 && !visited[x, y + 1]) {
    GoThrough(map, new [] {x, y + 1}); // south
    // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
  }
  if (x > 0 && map[x - 1, y] == 0 && !visited[x - 1, y]) {
    GoThrough(map, new [] {x - 1, y}); // west
    // ShowAtPosition(x, y)
  }
}
```

It will walk through the whole map and all reachable tiles and then walk back to the starting point.

Essentially, this is a flood fill algorithm that Matthew Strawbridge mentioned (while I was typing the answer).

Comment: Oh my god you people are awesome! I noticed that the Flood Fill Algorithm "cares" about not going through the same spot again, this is not a problem for me though. I can go through the same position of the map all the times that I want.

Comment: The code contained some bugs that were easy to spot and may contain some more bugs. I did not develop this in any IDE, compile or run this ever. You're not teleporting, but you're not outputting any reverse moves when you're returning from the recursion. Finally, you should understand the solution and not copy&paste it.